# Phonegap how does it work?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I am looking at making a hybrid app so I can code once and build for both Android and iPhone. I am looking into phone gap and am a little confused on how it works.

Can I build any mobile website using html and javascript and then package it into phone gap?

Does it just run as a "local" website on the mobile phone and use jquery to make data calls?

Comment: PhoneGap/Cordova is even much more than that! You should search the web for information about it. Such general questions are not needed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I build any mobile website using html and javascript and then
>   package it into phone gap?

Phonegap is for building Apps not websites. You can build webpages as *your view* in a webbrower, but it is not a website.

> Does it just run as a "local" website on the mobile phone and use
>   jquery to make data calls?

Again, it is NOT a website. Phonegap is NOT a webserver. Also Phonegap is NOT a webbrowser, but there is an inAppBrowser plugin. You can use Jquery, Angular, Ionic and others.

Please read.

http://phonegap.com/about/faq/

Comment: but its building an app using web technologies?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I build any mobile website...

Yes you can. PhoneGap can pack all of the files used for building website, and it can do more! You can use it's API to access some local functionalities. Refer to the [document](http://docs.phonegap.com/plugin-apis/).

> Does it just run as a "local"...

I think the answer is yes.